# Rails: Change Status Onclick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

[image]

I have the following where I am monitoring a job status. What I would like to do is be able to click each div and have a menu appear where I can change the status. Is this possible?

Comment: can you show how your code look like

Comment: Its a private code base I cannot.

Comment: you can do with `js`

Comment: If you can't show code, we can't help. This is not a "do my work" platform.